# Correct site to ask about a problem in Codeforces, CodeChef, and competitive programming sites

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

If I want to ask about a problem in [Codeforces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeforces) or any other competitive programming site.

What is the correct Stack Exchange site for those questions?

Comment: Stack Overflow or Codereview?

Comment: What is a “competitive programming site”?

Comment: Depends on the problem, we can't help you login or get your password back there, but we've sites for programming. [Our list of all sites is always worth keeping handy](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name). Check "How do I ask a good question" and "What is on topic" (in the help centre) on the target site to make sure your post is in good shape.

Comment: it isn't a problem that likes life problems, it's algorithmic problem or we can call it an exercise @ARogueAnt.

Comment: For codeforces  [CodeGolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201041/best-free-online-resources-to-learn-competitive-programming) is a no, while specific problems *might* be asked on more than one site (such as [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133928/question-on-codeforces-problem)) normally codeforces is asked on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=codeforces&searchOn=3) - we would benefit from a specific question being edited into your question **here**.

Comment: I think this question is possible to answer generally such that it would help anyone asking about these.  I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: No, I'm asking what is the stack exchange site that I can ask for an idea or an answer of a specific problem from competitive programming sites, your link has guidelines for which kinds of questions should be posted in each site, and don't tell any thing about correct place for competitive programming questions @gnat

Comment: Quoting from the linked question: "if your question generally covers… a specific programming problem... and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" – isn't that the answer to your question? Or perhaps the description under Computer Science? That your question arises from competitive programming may not matter at all. You should really edit this question to provide more detail about the actual question you want to ask.

Comment: The actual question I want to ask is : "Can some one help me is this [problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/351/problem/C) please ?, I stuck on it more than two days and didn't find any idea", now you know what is the question that I'm searching for a site for, Do you thing my post should be updated ? can it be improved or asked in clearer form ? Does anyone has an answer for it ?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an "actual" question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/839601)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Code Golf and Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) accepts two types of questions regarding competitive programming:

- An actual coding competition, such as code golf, with a clear and objective scoring criterion. Be sure to read their [Asking](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20862/66833) section on their Welcome page, and it is recommended you post these in their [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) to get feedback first.
- Tips on improving your score for an answer to a coding challenge, potentially on a different site. These questions should be tagged with [tips](/questions/tagged/tips), and should include, as a bare minimum:

  - Enough of a challenge specification to complete the challenge *without* having to go to another page,
  - Your current attempt and its score, and
  - What you've already tried to do to improve your score.

  For example, posting a long piece of code with long variable names and extra whitespace and asking for golfing advice wouldn't meet this third criterion. Linking to the challenge off-site, while helpful, doesn't fully meet the first point, and you should include at least a brief spec.

Anything else, such as questions *about* a competitive coding site or how to get started solving a challenge, are off-topic there.

Comment: thank for elaborated answer, I'm stuck on a problem in codeforces from 2 days, Can I get help in codegolf ?

Comment: @ahmadalghadban No. Help on completing challenges/problems isn't on-topic for Code Golf - that's more appropriate for SO

Comment: I downvoted this because I don't think CGCC really is the site for competitive programming.

Comment: @rak1507 There's a difference between posting competitive programming questions here and asking for tips on making some code faster that just happens to be a solution to a problem from that sort of competition. The answer puts requirements on questions, it doesn't say any question about CP is fine.

Comment: @rak1507 I definitely believe that CGCC is the SE site for competitive programming *under certain conditions* - namely, those I've laid out in this answer. Not every question that relates to competitive programming is on topic for CGCC, but I think the site is clearly *for* competitive programming, and, under certain circumstances (namely, [tips] questions), *about* competitive programming